# Seconds Behind Master column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MYSQL to display only the column Seconds_Behind_Master that you see when running show slave status in mysql?  I will later run the same code through OpenQuery in SQL

Thanks P

Answer (score 0):

As I was going to later run this through OpenQuery I have used the code below to achieve what I wanted.

```
select slave_io_running, slave_sql_running, seconds_behind_master into #status FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL_BRONTE_CREDITPerfect, 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS')
```